# What firebase license should I include in my app?

Tags: attribution, license-notice

I am using the library: `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0` Firebase in my app.

The library belongs this site: [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com)

My doubt is whether I have to include some license from firebase like the Apache 2.0 or MIT licenses. For example:

When I use a third party library, like [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs). The library owner, lets anyone use it, since it included the copyrights somewhere on the application for use it.
That is, when using this library, I have to refer to this [LICENSE.TXT](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) somewhere in my application.

My question is if I have to do the same for the library service "Firebase" and the libraries that Google provides, such as the "Design Support Library", among others.

Here are the Firebase terms: [Terms of Service Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/terms/terms-of-service.html)

And as other google libraries also have to include something?

```
com.android.support:design:23.1.1
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
```

Answer (score 4):

If I redistribute some third-party library in your Android app, I need to comply with its license terms.

For free and open source licenses, the terms usually include at least to provide some credits, notice and include the license texts.

For this firebase library, this is commercially licensed. So I need a commercial agreement first.

Per [its Maven POM](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/firebase/firebase-client-android/2.5.2/firebase-client-android-2.5.2.pom) I can see this:

```
license: Commercial
url: https://www.firebase.com/terms/terms-of-service.html
```

Now this library is proprietary but it also contains disclosed FLOSS code under MIT and Apache license as you I see in the `NOTICE_firebase_android` file found in the [Jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/firebase/firebase-client-android/2.5.2/firebase-client-android-2.5.2.jar)

I will need to make sure to carry these over in my app proper.