# How to add Firebase API's licence into our app?

Tags: licensing, license-notice, attribution

Like many other apps, whenever our app uses a third-party library, we add its licence to a page in our app displaying all third-party licences, be the licence MIT or Apache. Recently, we have added Firebase into out project through cocoapods(yes, this is an iOS app), and specifically `FirebaseCore`, `FirebaseAnalytics`, `FirebaseInstanceID` and `FirebaseMessaging` are installed in their compiled framework form, as opposed to their source form.

What licence should we add into our page? I have found this post:
[What firebase license should I include in my app?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2568/what-firebase-license-should-i-include-in-my-app)
But the only answer it android-specific and confusing, and does not directly mention what licence to use. I have personally found, however, that there is an Apache 2.0 licence in the beginning of some of the header files in the Firebase frameworks, should we use these licences?

Also, should we attribute each of these four APIs independently, or collectively as `Firebase`? I know there's a Firebase User Agreement and a Terms of Service, but that's just between us and Google, and has nothing to do with this kind of attribution or third-party licence, right?

Lastly, if possible, can someone also answer that if the same licence apply to Android as well? Since we do have an Android version of the same app, I would like to know if there's any difference in the frameworks licensing  across these two platforms.